# No able to open MIS Fit developer registration sign up page

Tags: rest, misfit

I am trying to integrate misfit data with one of our Web App. I could see 404 error when tried to open signup page of MISFit .
Details:
https://build.misfit.com/docs/cloudapi/get_started#preparation
Under **quick start** section there was link to signup page that was not working.
Sign up Page link.
https://build.misfit.com/signup
Could any body please help me with correct link to the signup process?

Comment: Did you go to the misfit.com website and look for contact information?  Bad website and documentation links is something the company can fix, not us.

Comment: Hi Dave, Yes I went through website misfit.com, I see its related customer signup not for developers it looks.